# Regular expression for multiline java

Tags: java, regex, scala

I need to parse and extract values from a sql log similar to the one below.

```
SQL^^0001^^ABCDEF^^26^^XYZ
SQL^^0002^^ABCDEF^^26^^XYZ
abc
<>()_asc wHERE
SQL^^0003^^ABCDEF^^12^^XYZ
SQL^^0004^^ABCDEF^^28^^XYZ
```

But the logs are not single lines always. I have a regex that can capture If it is single line. Also the fields are of fixed length except the last element. Last element can vary in length.

```
(\w{3})\W{2}(\d{4})\W{2}(\w{6})\W{2}(\d{2})\W{2}(.*)

^^ is the delimiter but can be any other value also.
```

There is no fixed end of line character but I need to capture until next line SQL in this case.
How to parse the log and extract them if its multi line log. I'm trying in Java. Java or scala is preferred.

Comment: Regex isn't a good tool for parsing input that spans multiple lines. If all the data records of interest start with the same pattern then one thing you could do is read the log into a single line of text (no newline `\n` characters) and then `split()` the text on the start-of-record pattern. After that you parse the individual elements.

Comment: Do new records start with `SQL^^` at the beginning of each line? To correctly handle such cases, we need to know the exact record starting pattern. Try [**this regex**](https://regex101.com/r/OrIqvz/1).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may leverage the fact that each record starts with exactly 3 word chars followed with `^^`. Thus, the last field you match should match any lines that do not start with that pattern. If the `^^` are just an example, you may just use the whole `\w{3}\W{2}\d{4}\W{2}\w{6}\W{2}\d{2}\W{2}` pattern as the delimiter instead of `^^`.

Use

```
(?m)^(\w{3})\W{2}(\d{4})\W{2}(\w{6})\W{2}(\d{2})\W{2}(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w{3}\^\^).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PMdN77/1). If the `^^` is just a placeholder, as mentioned above, replace `(?!\w{3}\^\^)` with `(?!\w{3}\W{2}\d{4}\W{2}\w{6}\W{2}\d{2}\W{2})`. Or, perhaps, a shorter one will do, too: `(?!\w{3}\W{2}\d{4}\b)`.

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line (`(?m)` is a `Pattern.MULTILINE` embedded flag option that makes `^` match a line start rather than a string start position)
- `(\w{3})` - Group 1: three word chars
- `\W{2}` - 2 non-word chars
- `(\d{4})` - Group 2: four digits
- `\W{2}` - 2 non-word chars
- `(\w{6})` - Group 3: six word chars
- `\W{2}` - 2 non-word chars
- `(\d{2})` - Group 4: 2 digits
- `\W{2}` - 2 non-word chars
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w{3}\^\^).*)*)` - Group 5:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\w{3}\^\^).*)*` - zero or more consecutive occurrences of:

    - `\r?\n(?!\w{3}\W{2})` - CRLF or LF line break not followed with 3 word and then 2 non-word chars
    - `.*` - the rest of the line